# Having problem using Stylesheet.create in react native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I am new to react native and having issues in styling the elements. I followed the articles which told to use StyleSheet.create() method and tried to style my elements but i am getting error

**The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.**
Here is my reference code

**MyComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-material-ui';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {header} from '../assets/css/style.js'

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {

    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={ styles.headerStyle }>
              <h2 style={ styles.headerMargin }> Hello! </h2>
            </div>
   }
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    headerStyle : header.headerStyle,
    headerMargin:header.headerMargin
});
```

**style.js**

```
export const header= {
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        paddingTop: '20px',
        paddingBottom: '20px',
        color: '#fff'
    },
    headerCenter: {
        width: '100%',
        textAlign: 'center',
        display: 'block'
    },
    headerMargin: {
        margin: '0',
        padding: '0'
    }
}
```

Comment: In React Native you have use (View and Text) instead (div and h2). Can you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In react native you need to set dimensions using integer values. Because RN will set dimensions using DP, instead pixel.

So, 0 can't be "0". To set a `paddingTop 20dp`, you would set `paddingTop: 20` (w/o px).

In your code, you are setting **0** as string (styles.js). This will throw error.

Use this fixed `style.js` code:

**styles.js**

```
export const header= {
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        paddingTop: 20,
        paddingBottom: 20,
        color: '#fff'
    },
    headerCenter: {
        width: '100%',
        textAlign: 'center',
        display: 'block'
    },
    headerMargin: {
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0
    }
}
```